# .NET TCP Server Dropping Connections

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, tcpserver

A while back I wrote a little application to implement a TCP Server, but as a newbie to C# .NET I just followed a tutorial. The authorization part of it works fine, but due to following the tutorial to closely, after the authorization is made, it drops the connection with tcpClient.Close();

How should I adjust this code to keep listening for more packets? I think most servers drop connections after X minutes, but I am still new to this type of thing.

```
// Starts the TCP RCON Server
public void StartServer()
{
    Console.WriteLine("RCON Server starting on Port: {0}", serverPort);

    this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, serverPort);
    this.listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
    this.listenThread.Start();

    Console.WriteLine("RCON Server has been Started.");
}

// Listen for Client Connections
private void ListenForClients()
{
    this.tcpListener.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        // blocks until a client has connected to the server
        TcpClient client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

        // Create a thread for client communication
        Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ReadClientPacket));
        clientThread.Start(client);
    }
}

private void ReadClientPacket(object client)
{
    TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
    NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

    bool terminate = false;

    while (!terminate)
    {
        try
        {
            int packetsize;

            // Create a new Packet Object and fill out the data from the incoming TCP Packets
            RCONPacket packet = new RCONPacket();

            using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(clientStream))
            {
                // First Int32 is Packet Size
                packetsize = reader.ReadInt32();

                packet.RequestId = reader.ReadInt32();
                packet.RconDataReceived = (RCONPacket.RCONDATA_rec)reader.ReadInt32();

                Console.WriteLine("Packet Size: {0} RequestID: {1} ServerData: {2}", packetsize, packet.RequestId, packet.RconDataReceived);

                // Read first and second String in the Packet (UTF8 Null Terminated)
                packet.String1 = ReadBytesString(reader);
                packet.String2 = ReadBytesString(reader);

                Console.WriteLine("String1: {0} String2: {1}", packet.String1, packet.String2);

                switch (packet.RconDataReceived)
                {
                    case RCONPacket.RCONDATA_rec.SERVERDATA_AUTH:
                    {
                        if (packet.String1 == "testpass")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Password is Valid");
                            ReplyAuthRequest(packet.RequestId, tcpClient, packet.String1); // Junk Packet
                            ReplyAuthRequest(packet.RequestId, tcpClient, packet.String1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Password is Invalid");
                            ReplyAuthRequest(BAD_PASSWORD, tcpClient, packet.String1); // Junk Packet
                            ReplyAuthRequest(BAD_PASSWORD, tcpClient, packet.String1);

                            terminate = true;
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                    case RCONPacket.RCONDATA_rec.SERVERDATA_EXECCOMMAND:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("RCON Command Packet Received");
                        ReplyExecCommand(packet.RequestId, tcpClient);

                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            terminate = true;
        }
    }

    tcpClient.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you notice, you have a lot of `break` statements. I am not clear on the entire design of your program, but if you remove those and then add a check for a `boolean` value in your while loop such as`while(!terminated) { .. }`, this would ensure that whenever your application tells the program to end or to stop listening, the loop will also be terminated because you would set `terminated` to `true`. What you are saying by `while(true)` is to continue forever until `break`occurs, which then subsequently breaks out of the while loop and calls `.Close()`.

Comment: That makes sense, but isn't that basically what I am doing with break; except it just makes it more readable? I have updated the code so you might get a better idea of what I am doing. I am trying to implement this protocol http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_RCON_Protocol as a server. Problem I am running into is that even when removing that break; that was stopping the ReadClientPacket() after the first packet, now I get the error "Stream was not readable" after it looks through one time

Comment: btw, I will mark yours as the answer shortly. Just wanted to leave it open a bit longer to see if I can go ahead and get this problem resolved. Thanks for the good answer!

Comment: I think I just figured it out. Should I just remove the while loop and the tcpClient.Close()? Would that make it so that the entire function is called again when the next packet is received?

Comment: @Brett: I think your design is a little off... before the while loop you should check if you actually have any data in the stream, otherwise you are building packets for nothing.